# How to remove special characters of input field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events, frappe

I have form with 4 fields (item_code, item_name, item_search, description)
If user fill the first input field (item_code), at the end it automatically sets the same value for all the other three input field.

While setting the value I want to remove special characters in one field(item search).

So I tried "replace", I don't know what mistake am I doing because I'm a beginner.

```
item_code: function(frm) {
if(!frm.doc.item_name)
frm.set_value("item_name", frm.doc.item_code);
if(!frm.doc.item_search)
frm.set_value("item_search", frm.doc.item_code.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "_");
if(!frm.doc.description)
frm.set_value("description", frm.doc.item_code);
},
```

Comment: what is your expected output if that string is "abc's test#s";

Comment: Why is this [tag:python]

Answer (score 1):

i checked replace function is not working properly.
change your **.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "_")** with below code.

**.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")**

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'A2.11^11*111"@';
string = string.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g,'');
console.log(string);
```